# How to create raw transactions for erc20tokens using python? Is there any api to send and receive transactions?

Tags: ether, erc-20, python

I want to create raw transactions for erc20tokens. I want to know how to create addresses for erc20tokens and also to send and receive coins using python. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an example using web3.py to read out information about on ERC20 token here: https://github.com/carver/ethtoken.py

Pretty much all you need to write this yourself is the ABI for ERC20, and a web3.py instance.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend, you could have found this one very easely ;)

Check this! [web3.py](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py)